# exemptions of federal employment for Schedule A disabled applicants

Tags: employment, us-federal-government

If you are permanently disabled, and a job posting by the federal government (Army, Veterans Affairs, etc...) requires you to be a member (Army = registered with a recruiter prior to age 36; VA = registered for Selective Service System prior to age 26), can you be exempt from this requirement for applying for that particular position?  When I was younger, I was told I couldn't apply with the military, so I never signed up for these things because of my disability.  It seems silly to require them when applying for a job, especially since I have a Schedule A letter from my doctor saying I have a permanent disability.

For an Army example, HR from the National Guard told me to discuss with an Army Recruiter in my area for a computer scientist position which I'm qualified for.  He told me the position is for Army personnel only.  The HR person also told me that the position is exempt from Schedule A, so I need to meet all qualifications, which requires this Army National Guard membership after recruitment.

https://state.nationalguard.com/wisconsin

For a VA example, I have not spoken to HR from the VA quite yet, but I'm inquiring about another position with them that wouldn't require any physical abilities, but requires you to be registered with the Selective Service System.  But I'm too old to apply now.  So I will find out from the VA soon here.

https://www.sss.gov/Registration/Register-Now/Registration-Form